# Empty button listener

Tags: java, user-interface

I've only been working with Java for about a year now and have just gotten into the basics of GUI. I'm writing a program that will calculate the center of mass between 2, 3, 4, or 5 points (user's option). Depending on the number of points the user wants to enter, a number of editable JTextFields appear to get input for coordinates and masses of those coordinates. Unfortunately, when asked to calculate the center of mass, the button won't display what I want. The way it's written now is the only way I've gotten it to compile/run without an empty string error. I believe it has to do with how I've initialized the variables/where they're initialized between constructors, but I can't for the life of me figure out where that problem lies exactly. Any help will be greatly appreciated! I've attached the code - I know it's long, but you never know what can be useful. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ComboBox extends JFrame
/*************VARIABLES*******************************************************/
{
   private final int WIDTH = 1500;
   private final int HEIGHT = 1500;
   private JPanel northPanel;
   private JPanel centerPanel;

private JPanel blankPanel;
private JPanel pointsPanel;
private JPanel selectedPointsPanel;
private JComboBox pointsBox;
private JTextField selectedPoints;
private JLabel selection;
private String choose = "Choose an option...";
private String twoPoints = "2 points";
private String threePoints = "3 points";
private String fourPoints = "4 points";
private String fivePoints = "5 points";
private String[] points = {choose, twoPoints, threePoints, fourPoints, fivePoints};

private JPanel coordinatesPanel;
private JPanel cPanel;
private JTextField xField1; 
private JTextField xField2;
private JTextField xField3;
private JTextField xField4;
private JTextField xField5;
private JTextField yField1;
private JTextField yField2;
private JTextField yField3;
private JTextField yField4;
private JTextField yField5;
private JLabel instructions; 
private JLabel X;
private JLabel Y;
private JLabel blankLabel; 

private JPanel massPanel;
private JTextField mass1 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass2 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass3 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass4 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass5 = new JTextField(10);
private JLabel instructions2;

Boolean calcBool = false;
private JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");

private JPanel displayPanel;
private double centerX;
private double centerY;
private JLabel display; 

private double x1, x2, x3, x4, x5;
private double y1, y2, y3, y4, y5;
private double m1, m2, m3, m4, m5;


/**********************************WINDOW************************************/  
public ComboBox()
{
  super("Choose an option");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  setResizable(true);
  setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  buildPointsPanel();
  buildCoordinatesPanel();
  buildMassPanel();
  buildDisplayPanel();
  buildBlankPanel();

  add(pointsPanel);
  add(coordinatesPanel);
  add(massPanel);
  add(blankPanel);
  add(calcButton);
  add(blankPanel);
  add(resetButton);
  add(blankPanel);
  add(displayPanel);

  calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
  pointsBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());
  //resetButton.addActionListener(new ResetButtonListener());

  pack();
  setVisible(true);
```

}

```
/************************BUILD ALL THE PANELS**********************/
private void buildBlankPanel()
{
  blankPanel = new JPanel();
}
private void buildPointsPanel()
{
  pointsPanel = new JPanel();
     pointsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
  pointsBox = new JComboBox(points);
  pointsBox.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());
  pointsPanel.add(pointsBox);
  selection = new JLabel("You selected: ");
  selectedPoints = new JTextField(10);
  selectedPoints.setEditable(false);
  pointsPanel.add(selection);
  pointsPanel.add(selectedPoints);
}

private void buildCoordinatesPanel()
{
  coordinatesPanel = new JPanel();
  coordinatesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
  instructions = new JLabel("Please enter the X and Y values of your points below.");
  JLabel blank = new JLabel("");
  X = new JLabel("X values");
  Y = new JLabel("Y values");
  blankLabel = new JLabel("");

  coordinatesPanel.add(instructions);
  coordinatesPanel.add(blankLabel);
  coordinatesPanel.add(X);
  coordinatesPanel.add(Y);

  xField1 = new JTextField(10);
     xField1.setEditable(true);
  yField1 = new JTextField(10);
   yField1.setEditable(true);
  xField2 = new JTextField(10);
     xField2.setEditable(true);
  yField2 = new JTextField(10);
     yField2.setEditable(true);
  xField3 = new JTextField(10);
   xField3.setEditable(true);
  yField3 = new JTextField(10);
   yField3.setEditable(true);
  xField4 = new JTextField(10);
   xField4.setEditable(true);
  yField4 = new JTextField(10);
   yField4.setEditable(true);
  xField5 = new JTextField(10);
   xField5.setEditable(true);
  yField5 = new JTextField(10);
   yField5.setEditable(true);
}

private void buildMassPanel()
{
  massPanel = new JPanel();
  instructions2 = new JLabel("Please enter the masses of your points");
  massPanel.add(instructions2);
  mass1.setEditable(true);
  mass2.setEditable(true);
  mass3.setEditable(true);
  mass4.setEditable(true);
  mass5.setEditable(true);
}

private void buildDisplayPanel()
{
   displayPanel = new JPanel();
  //display = new JLabel("The center of mass is located at (" + centerX + "," + centerY
  +").");
  //displayPanel.add(display);
 }

/********************************COMBOBOX LISTENER****************************/     
private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  { //The following asks the user to select the number of points they want and stores
       it
     String select =(String) pointsBox.getSelectedItem();
     selectedPoints.setText(select);

  //The following determines how many text fields to display depending on how many     
    points the user wants

     if (select==twoPoints)
     {
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField2);

        massPanel.add(mass1);
        massPanel.add(mass2);

centerX = ((m1*x1)+(m2*x2)/(m1+m2));
        centerY = ((m1*y1)+(m2*y2)/(m1+m2));
      }
     if (select==threePoints)
     {
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField3);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField3);

        massPanel.add(mass1);
        massPanel.add(mass2);
        massPanel.add(mass3);

    centerX = ((m1*x1)+(m2*x2)+(m3*x3)/(m1+m2+m3));
        centerY = ((m1*y1)+(m2*y2)+(m3*y3)/(m1+m2+m3));
     }
     if (select==fourPoints)
     {
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField3);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField3);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField4);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField4);

        massPanel.add(mass1);
        massPanel.add(mass2);
        massPanel.add(mass3);
        massPanel.add(mass4);

    centerX = ((m1*x1)+(m2*x2)+(m3*x3)+(m4*x4)/(m1+m2+m3+m4));
        centerY = ((m1*y1)+(m2*y2)+(m3*y3)+(m4*y4)/(m1+m2+m3+m4));
        }
     if (select==fivePoints)
     {
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField1);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField2);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField3);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField3);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField4);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField4);
        coordinatesPanel.add(xField5);
        coordinatesPanel.add(yField5);

        massPanel.add(mass1);
        massPanel.add(mass2);
        massPanel.add(mass3);
        massPanel.add(mass4);
        massPanel.add(mass5);

    centerX = ((m1*x1)+(m2*x2)+(m3*x3)+(m4*x4)+(m5*x5)/(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5));
        centerY = ((m1*y1)+(m2*y2)+(m3*y3)+(m4*y4)+(m5*y5)/(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5));
     }
     if (select==choose)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a valid option");
     }
  }
}
/********************************CALC BUTTON LISTENER******************************/   
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    display = new JLabel("The center of mass is located at (" + centerX + "," + centerY
     +").");
displayPanel.add(display);
  }       

}
/******************************MAIN METHOD***************************/      
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  new ComboBox();
}
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant parts of your code. Also whats the result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is instantiate the `display`, where you have it declared.

```
JLabel display = new JLabel("  ");
```

Then add it to the GUI, wherever in the code you're adding all the other components. Than in your listener class, just set the text

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    display.setText("some text");
}
```

The way you're doing it might mess up your desired GUI formatting. If you were to do it though, you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding any new components. I'd recommend using the former.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where is your specific problem, but looking at your code i see some potential bugs. In java you compare objects equality with `equals()` not with `==` .`==` is just for references.

So changes all lines where you compare Strings with `==` replace with `equals`.

For example change

`select==fivePoints`
to

```
select.equals(fivePoints)
```

Having attributes like

```
private JTextField mass1 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass2 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass3 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass4 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField mass5 = new JTextField(10);
```

is not the best way, you can store them in a `Collection` or in array.

```
private List<JTextField> masses;
```

Always when you add a component call `revalidate` and `repaint`.

```
  display = new JLabel("The center of mass is located at (" + centerX + "," + centerY
     +").");
displayPanel.add(display);
displayPanel.revalidate();
displayPanel.repaint();
```